# including c header in c++ file

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to include a "c" header file in a cpp file.
The c header file has the keyword "Boolean".

c header looks something like this:

```
#ifndef _CONFIGSTORE_H_
#define _CONFIGSTORE_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
Boolean ConfigStoreIsPassword(char *pName);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //_CONFIGSTORE_H_
```

Below is the way i am including the c header in my cpp file:

```
extern "C"{
#include "configstore.h"
}
```

or

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include "configstore.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Either way i include, i get the below error:
../../../../src/Common/framework/configstore.h:52: error: 'Boolean' does not name a type

Could you please let me know how i can add the c header in cpp file
Thanks in advance!!

-Vasavi

Comment: Has nothing to do with C or C++. You just need to define the type (or include the file that has the definition).

Comment: `Boolean` is not a type in C or C++. Do you have a `typedef` or macro somewhere because this would be unusable in C.

Comment: The include works, there is a problem related to your `Boolean` type.

Comment: putting `extern "C"` before including is not needed, the header shall do the job, not the user code (c/cpp file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things spring to mind here.  One, you are nesting an `extern "C"` block inside another `extern "C"` block.  Remove the outer blocks.

Two, `Boolean` is not a keyword in c++.  `bool` is.  Try adding `typedef bool Boolean;` before your header inclusion.

Comment: "boolean" is not a C++ type either, it is "bool".

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean` is not a standard type for either `C` or `C++`.

You'll need to find the header where `Boolean` is declared and include it before including your file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a definition of the `Boolean` type, that the C++ compiler can understand.

The `extern "C"` stuff just affects how symbol names are mangled, it doesn't magically make the C++ compiler understand C-specific types.

Not that `Boolean` is valid C, anyway. There's probably another header missing from your includes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need and should not use `extern "C"` around the `#include` statement. The header already does this right. `configstore.h` needs to include the definition of `Boolean`. As others have mentioned, you could add the definition of `Boolean` to the source file (or include the definition) before including `configstore.h`, but this is a bad idea as it creates include order dependencies between unrelated modules.