# How do I write a C header file that can be used in C++ programs?

Tags: c++, c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check (via the preprocessor) if a C source file is being compiled as C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149229/how-to-check-via-the-preprocessor-if-a-c-source-file-is-being-compiled-as-c)

I'm trying to find a standard macro which will test whether a header file is being compiled as C or as C++. The purpose of this is that the header may be included by either C or C++ code, and must behave slightly differently depending on which. Specifically:

In C, I need this to be the code:

```
extern size_t insert (const char*);
```

In C++, I need this to be the code:

```
extern "C" size_t insert (const char*);
```

Additionally, is there a way to avoid putting #ifdef's around every declaration in the header?

Comment: I may be biased, but I would argue that this question additionally has to do with extern. Since I had not known about the "extern { ... }" syntax previously, my selected answer is much more helpful than the one given in your proposed duplicate. I will edit the question to show this difference.

Comment: I've left an x-ref to this question on the proposed duplicate.  You could improve the distinction between the two by a revised title such as 'How to conditionally define `extern "C"` or just `extern` auto-detecting the C or C++ compiler?" or something along those general lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've edited the title to reflect what (I think) is really being asked, as illustrated by the example in the text. ... searching for this did, however, reveal a duplicate title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742534/including-c-header-in-c-file ... but not duplicate content.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712707/extern-functions-in-c-vs-c in which you gave a lengthy answer that covers the question here, under "Issue 2: Inter-working between C and C++".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is normal to bracket C header files as follows so they can be used in C++ programs. Check your system header files such as stdio.h and you will probably see this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 15):

The answer is to use the macro __cplusplus. In this instance, the most straightforward approach is:

```
extern
#ifdef __cplusplus
"C"
#endif
size_t insert (const char*);
```

This macro is part of the C++ standard.

Comment: And if you want to do this for multiple functions, the norm is `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif` ... `#ifdef __cplusplus } #endif`.

Comment: Another possibility: `#ifdef __cplusplus` ... `#define EXTERN extern "C"` ... `#else` ... `#define EXTERN extern` ... `#endif` (where ... denotes a newline)

Comment: g++ does not like 

#define EXTERN extern "C"

it wines so:

error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Answer (score 7):

You might find it reasonable to define three macros to help with this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C_BEGIN extern "C" {
#define EXTERN_C_END   }
#define EXTERN_C       extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERN_C_BEGIN /* Nothing */
#define EXTERN_C_END   /* Nothing */
#define EXTERN_C       extern /* Or Nothing */
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

This would be most useful in a standard header that's included in most places in your project.  For a single function, you might write:

```
EXTERN_C size_t insert(const char *name);
```

For a group of functions, you might write:

```
EXTERN_C_BEGIN

size_t other_insert(const char *name);
size_t other_delete(const char *name);
size_t other_update(const char *old_name, const char *new_name);

EXTERN_C_END
```

It is permissible to include `extern` in front of the individual functions inside the `EXTERN_C_BEGIN` to `EXTERN_C_END` block.